# YAML - Fix my format please (String)

Tags: yaml, minecraft

I am making a minecraft server, but I have encountered a problem in YAML when configuring the console to execute the command. How can I fix this formatting.

```
white:
  COMMAND: 'say:&aYou have purchased a White horse for $5; console: summon EntityHorse 6 74 52 {Type:0,Variant:0,CustomName:"{player}'s Horse",CustomNameVisible:1,PersistenceRequired:1b,Attributes:[{Name:"generic.maxHealth",Base:40}],SaddleItem:{id:saddle},Tame:1,Rotation:[90f,0f]}'
```

I believe it is a problem with the quotation marks, should I double quote? it works for apostrophy (''). So should I ("")?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by making the apostrophies that are inside the string double ('') instead of single ('). Because they interfere with the ('string') aprostrophies on the edges of the string.